Name of movie where a red ballon is the star
I saw most of this movie back in the early 90's at school. No idea how old it was back then. Doubt it was a blockbuster movie. Possibly foreign. 
The movie was about a red balloon that seemed to be alive. There was a little boy who was friends with the balloon. During a later scene, a few bullies threw rocks at the balloon and may have "killed" it. Not sure. I believe it may have ended with the balloon floating into the sky to join a large group of balloons. 
What was the name of this movie?

It is called The Red Balloon.

The thirty-four minute short, which follows the adventures of a young boy who one day finds a sentient, mute, red balloon, was filmed in the Ménilmontant neighborhood of Paris, France.
In their wanderings around the neighborhood, Pascal and the balloon encounter a gang of 
  bullies, who are envious of his balloon, and they soon destroy his new friend.
  The film ends as the other balloons in Paris come to Pascal's aid and take him on a cluster balloon ride over the city.

